# Is method overriding (without virtual methods or pointers) considered a part of Polymorphism?

Tags: c++, object, inheritance, polymorphism

First of all, I would like to say that I searched for similar questions, but the answers seem to focus on different things.

I started learning C++ but I have a problem understanding what exactly is considered as ***polymorphism***. I have written two different programs.

In the first, I don't use virtual methods or pointers to objects.

In the second, I use a **virtual method** (area) and an array with pointers to objects.

I understand that the second program is using polymorphism (a parent class pointer is used to point to a child class object).

But since the first program produces the exact same results by **overriding** the function area, is it considered to be using polymorphism too?

**Program 1**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Polygon {
protected:
    float base;
    float height;
public:
    Polygon(): base(0), height(0) {}
    Polygon(float b, float h): base(b), height(h) {}
    float area() {return -1;}
};

class Triangle:public Polygon {
public:
    Triangle(): Polygon() {}
    Triangle(float b, float h): Polygon(b,h) {}
    float area() {return base*height/2;}
};

class Rectangle:public Polygon {
public:
    Rectangle(): Polygon() {}
    Rectangle(float b, float h): Polygon(b,h) {}
    float area() {return base*height;}
};

int main() {
    //Overriding area method without pointers
    Triangle t1, t2(10,10);
    Rectangle r1, r2(5,5);
    cout<<t1.area()<<endl;  //Output: 0
    cout<<t2.area()<<endl;  //Output: 50
    cout<<r1.area()<<endl;  //Output: 0
    cout<<r2.area()<<endl;  //Output: 25
    cout<<t1.Polygon::area()<<endl; //Output: -1
}
```

**Program 2**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Polygon {
protected:
    float base;
    float height;
public:
    Polygon(): base(0), height(0) {}
    Polygon(float b, float h): base(b), height(h) {}
    virtual float area() {return -1;} //virtual method area
};

class Triangle:public Polygon {
public:
    Triangle(): Polygon() {}
    Triangle(float b, float h): Polygon(b,h) {}
    float area() {return base*height/2;}
};

class Rectangle:public Polygon {
public:
    Rectangle(): Polygon() {}
    Rectangle(float b, float h): Polygon(b,h) {}
    float area() {return base*height;}
};

int main() {
    //Polymorphism
    Triangle t1, t2(10,10);
    Rectangle r1, r2(5,5);
    Polygon *ptr[]={&t1,&t2,&r1,&r2};
    cout<<ptr[0]->area()<<endl;  //Output: 0
    cout<<ptr[1]->area()<<endl; //Output: 50
    cout<<ptr[2]->area()<<endl; //Output: 0
    cout<<ptr[3]->area()<<endl; //Output: 25
    cout<<ptr[0]->Polygon::area()<<endl;    //Output: -1
}
```

Comment: **TL;DR** As from your question title: It depends. There's also [_static polymorhpism_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) that doesn't require `virtual` functions.

Comment: The only kind of overriding in C++ is of virtual functions, but there are many kinds of polymorphism.

Answer (score 3):

> But since the first program produces the exact same results by **overriding** the function area, is it considered to be using polymorphism too?

Well, no. There's no ***overriding*** in the 1st sample, but shadowing of the base class function implementations.

---

That your examples produce the same results is because of the fact, that in your 1st sample

```
    cout<<t1.area()<<endl;  //Output: 0
    cout<<t2.area()<<endl;  //Output: 50
    cout<<r1.area()<<endl;  //Output: 0
    cout<<r2.area()<<endl;  //Output: 25
```

you are calling functions with concrete class instances.

Something like

```
    Polygon *ptr[]={&t1,&t2,&r1,&r2};
    cout<<ptr[0]->area()<<endl;  //Output: 0
    cout<<ptr[1]->area()<<endl; //Output: 50
    cout<<ptr[2]->area()<<endl; //Output: 0
    cout<<ptr[3]->area()<<endl; //Output: 25
```

[would fail](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0efdd720af496258) being used with this code.

---

*Polymorphism* means that you have some interface declared, that might be accessed through a base class reference.

In c++ you have generally the choice of

- Dynamic polymorphism (i.e. abstract/virtual base classes) and resolve overridden function calls at run time
- Static polymorphism (i.e. using the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to resolve overridden function calls at compile time)